# Exporting pandas data to excel - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have created a pivot table in pandas, & id like to export the pivot table to an excel file. But everytime I run the file, I dont get an error but the pivot table is also not being exported. view the code below

```
wb.create_sheet("sumPiv")
df4 = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx","SQL")
sumPiv = pd.pivot_table(df4,index = ['Ship_Date_Year'],
                           values = ['CustomerFuel'],
                           aggfunc = ('sum'),
                           margins = True)
sumPiv.to_excel('Test.xlsx' , sheet_name = 'sumPiv')
print(sumPiv)
```

I am using Test.xlsx data to create a pivot table & I want to export the pivot table back to Test.xlsx, in 'sumPiv' sheet. But for some reason this wont work.

What does work is if I create a new excel file when exporting, for ex:     `sumPiv.to_excel('Newfile.xlsx' , sheet_name = 'sumPiv')`. This would work just fine but I dont want to create another excel file, I want to put the pivottable back into Test.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `sumPiv.to_excel('Test.xlsx' , sheet_name = 'sumPiv') print(sumPiv)` you can add additional parameters for the start row or start column of your data.

So your line would change to `sumPiv.to_excel('Test.xlsx' , sheet_name = 'sumPiv', startrow=<row_number>) print(sumPiv)`

Additionally, you could read in the data on that sheet with `df = pd.read_excel('path/to/excel/file')` and then append the new data to that `df` dataframe.

Comment: `df4 = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx","SQL")

sumPiv = pd.pivot_table(df4,index = ['Ship_Date_Year'],

                           values = ['Customer_Amt_Excl_Fuel'],

                           aggfunc = ('sum'),

                           margins = True)

sumPiv.to_excel('Test.xlsx' , sheet_name = 'sumPiv', startrow=2) 

print(sumPiv)`

see the changes I made, still doesnt export the table to the excel file

Comment: Did you try to  append ```sumPiv``` to ```df4``` ?